# How to you calculate the Mauchly Test by hand

Tags: anova, sphericity

I am creating a web application that is supposed to perform a Mauchly Test but I cannot find hand written or worked examples anywhere. It is imperative that the answer must not provide examples using applications such as SPSS or R etc as I will be doing all calculation through PHP.

Would somebody be able to show the working for this?

[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: +1 Accurate, useful accounts of this test are remarkably difficult to find.  The best resource that seems readily available is the source code for an `R` package!

Comment: Agreed. Looking at other source code is not my preferred way and also not an option as i have no means of getting R. 

Would you happen to know of any links that show an example of a handwritten Mauchly Test? Thanks for your reply in the first instance

Comment: FWIW, `R` is freely available: visit https://cran.r-project.org/.

Comment: Mauchly, John W. (1940). Significance Test for Sphericity of a Normal $n$-Variate Distribution. The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 11(2), 204–209. doi:10.1214/aoms/1177731915